# Can we get colour options added to the "Colorful Comments" power?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, unicoins, april-fools

I just used my hard-earned Unicoins to purchase the Colorful Comments power, and it's great. I only find one thing lacking; the colour can't be changed! Eeeeek! After seeing the wide and varied range of colours listed in the Top Bar Color Chooser, I had expected there would be a similar range of options for the comments.

This must be fixed! Please add a similar range of options to the Colorful Comments power.

Comment: Here it is working fine. I strongly think the problem is with your computer. please check on your friends system.

Comment: @Mr_Green Oh, don't get me wrong, the feature is working great for me. I just want some customizability.

Comment: @BillyMailman its just for today, I don't think they would waste their time for such things

Comment: @Mr.Alien [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicoins+status-completed) seems to suggest otherwise; they've been patching it a fair bit already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already chose the best <s>colour</s> color for you, so you don't have to worry about it. You're welcome!

Comment: Pah! I wanted a choice between green-blue and teal!

Comment: Wow, so many people on stack and you managed to choose everyone favorites. Wow you guys are great!

Comment: -1 for changing the correct spelling of "colour" to "color" :(

Comment: That said, +1 for awesome colours from the start